# Gtk.TreeModel subclassing

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, treemodel

being french I am bad in english, sorry.

I upgrade an application running with python and pygtk with python and pyobject for Gtk3. It is difficult to find complete documentation on pyGobject, and I want to map a treemodel with sqlalchemy.

I'm stuck on this error when I want subclassing Gtk.TreeModel :

```
class AlchemyListStore(Gtk.TreeModel):

def __init__(self, types):
     Gtk.TreeModel.__init__(self)
     ...
```

The first line return:

```
...
File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/gi/types.py", line 205, in _type_register
_gobject.type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
TypeError: argument must be a GObject subclass
```

Under pyGtk, it was gtk.GenericTreeModel and it worked well...

I found on [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/Custom_Models) a example in C and I quote:

> [...] we need some boilerplate code to register our custom model with the GObject type system.

How does it work with pyObject? Is this a good track?
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gtk.TreeModel` is an interface not a class so:

```
class AlchemyListStore(GObject.Object, Gtk.TreeModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```